# Enforcing fragment cache generation based on specific criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

A view is generated with a link that includes a set of params

```
<%= link_to "blob", chosen_bilancinos_path(x: 0, y: session[:focusdate], z: session[:structure_id]) %>
```

and components that need caching

```
<% cache "x-#{params[:x]}_y-#{params[:y]}_z-#{params[:z]}" do %>
  <%= number_with_precision(cdg_other_costs, :precision => 1, :delimiter => "\u00a0") %>
  [...]
<% end %>
```

Note: development.rb has `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` specified.
However, if I test the output after changing the value of a y parameter on the search, the cache mechanism has not realised that the data has changed and that a new cache needs to be generated.

The controller action defines the root data objects that require caching

```
@last_correction = Correction.where(['analisi_id = ? AND profit_center_id = ?', session[:analisidate], session[:profit_center_id]]).order('updated_at DESC').first.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:number)
if @last_correction.nil?
  @last_update = Bilancino.order('updated_at DESC').where(['analisi_id = ?', session[:analisidate]]).first.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:number)
else
  @last_update = @last_correction
end
```

Helper methods builds upon the controller generated data and requires additionally cached data before hitting the view

```
def cdg_base(cdg_id)
  b = Bilancino.where(['cdg_id = ? AND id IN (?) AND pc_id = ?', cdg_id.to_i, @bilancinos, params[:z]]).map(&:balance).sum
  r = Correction.where(['cdg_id = ? AND analisi_id = ? AND pc_id = ?', cdg_id.to_i, params[:y], params[:z]]).map(&:value).sum
  b + r
end

def cdg_other_costs
  cdg_base(9)
end
```

Although the data for trip-wiring a new cache generation is available, it is not apparent between the [rails caching guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) or [other documentation](https://blog.ragnarson.com/2016/11/02/introduction-to-fragment-caching-in-rails.html) where controller and helper logic needs to be tied to the cached fragment.

Comment: A problem is that you are creating a cache key solely based on the user input (the params). You need to add the timestamp of the last created or updated record to avoid the fragment becoming stale as records are modified.

Comment: Also if the y, x, z params are passed as query parameters you can use the request path as a cache key instead of adding them manually. But I would consider if using fragment caching for search results is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @max (alias one of the better avatars), thus generate the most recent updated_at from the array of records, add it to view cache (as instance variable 'aa') and have the controller calculate most recent updated_at from the array as that variable?  thus rails will search for instance variable (+3 params) and determine if cache exists?

Comment: Or use russian doll caching and use `<% cache @bilancinos do %>` on the inner. Make sure you remove `.to_a` in the controller. Use `.load` instead if you want to force loading.

Comment: @max Updated question, as I realised that I had not specified problem properly.  There are two classes from which the last update can be derived, one of which `Correction` may be nil.  How does one specify the @last_update? `<% cache ["x-#{params[:x]}_y-#{params[:y]}_z-#{params[:z]}", @last_update] do %>`?